# how to set focus on textitem in oracle forms 11g?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

i am making calculator in oracle forms 11g

My requirement is when button press then focus on textitem

how to achieve this target?

Answer (score 2):

You should create a `when-button-pressed` trigger on the button.
In the when-button-pressed trigger you can use the `GO_ITEM built-in` to go to an item on of a specified block. After this action the focus will stay on the item specified:

> GO_ITEM('blockname.itemname');

Answer (score 1):

By using the `GO_ITEM` built-in, such as

```
GO_ITEM('your_block.text_item_name');
```